# Header() is not working in php

Tags: php

When I am submitting my form ,Its not redirecting to another page.
Here is my code....

```
<?php
 include 'header.php';


  if ( $_REQUEST['commit'] )
{ 

 header("Location: ../newfolder/DIGITAL-FASTLANE-MULTILINGUAL-ENGAGEMENT.php"); } 

                  ?>
                <form name="digitran"  method='post' action='DIGITAL-FASTLANE-MULTILINGUAL-ENGAGEMENT.php' >

                <div class="digitran">
                <img style="height:186px;margin-top:-95px;width:180px;"  src="images/DigiTran_new.png"  />
                </div>

                    <span><input align='right' placeholder='Organization Name'  style='width:50%;' name='OrgName' type='text'> </span>
                    <span><input align='right' placeholder='Name' style='width:50%;' type='text' name='ContName'> </span>
                    <span><input type='text' align='right' placeholder='Designation' style='width:50%;' name='Designation'></span> 
                    <span><input type='text' align='right' placeholder='Email' style='width:50%;' name='Email'></span> 
                    <span><input type='text' align='right' placeholder='Phone' style='width:50%;' name='Phone'></span> 

                                   <input type='submit' name='commit' value='Register'>
                </form>
```

Comment: Than close this question

Comment: Try changing `if ( $_REQUEST['commit'] )` to `if (isset($_POST['commit']))`

Comment: note, with this code as it stands, none of anything in your inputs will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Are your headers already being sent?

Most likely yes, due to output in header.php...

A quick fix would be to use output buffering in your script. Something like

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'header.php';
```

Then all the way at the bottom of your script you could do:

```
ob_end_flush();
```

This is very quick and dirty but it should do the job. I would encourage you to familiarize yourself with output buffering in general before using the solution.

Comment: No .headers  has not sent in header.php.

Comment: If there is any output whatsoever in header.php (whitespaces / html / etc) your headers will already be sent. PHP automatically sends headers right before your output begins

Answer (score 0):

it will not work untill you use php `header` location on the very 1st line of php file.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['commit'])) {
ob_start();
header("Location: ../newfolder/DIGITAL-FASTLANE-MULTILINGUAL-ENGAGEMENT.php");
    ob_clean();
    ob_end_flush();
}
?>

//your form here
```